# Side menu swipe functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm using Sidr jQuery plugin as a side menu on my application. Currently, the side menu toggles (open and closes) on a button click.

HTML:

```
<a id="right-menu" href="#sidr-menu">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">LOGIN/&nbsp;SIGNUP
 </button>
</a>

<div id="sidr" class="sidr right">
 <nav class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a  class="page-scroll" href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="{% url 'signup' %}">SIGN UP</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
 $('#right-menu').sidr({
 name: 'sidr-right',
 side: 'right',
 source:'#sidr',
 });
</script>
```

Now I want to add a swipe functionality for mobile devices so that a user can easily swipe left (to open the side menu) or swipe right (to close the side menu). How do I achieve this? And what library do I use?

Comment: hammer js or touchswipe js are popular and easy to use pluggings. You tagged your question JQM so if you are using that framework it has inbuilt swipe functionlaity

Answer (score 0):

You should check [jquery mobile swipe  documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

Answer (score 0):

IONIC framework is newly added. It will do all neccesary things for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I'm late, but you might want to try this simple code (Of course, you need to modify it to suit your code)

```
<script>
      $(window).touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function() {
          // Close
          $.sidr('close', 'sidr-main');
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
          // Open
          $.sidr('open', 'sidr-main');
        },
        preventDefaultEvents: false
      });
</script>
```

You need to try this in touch enabled device. Swiping by mouse doesn't seem to work.
I was writing my own custom jQuery  plugin for swipable side menu and was struck. Here is my [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796546/swipeable-side-menu-not-working)