# Swipeable side menu not working

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote a custom swipeable side menu for a responsive page (for mobile  page):
Here is the code:
**`jQuery code:`**

```
$(window).load(function(){
            $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
              var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
              $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
            });
            $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                {
                  if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                       $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                       return false;
                  }
                  if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                       $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                       return false;
                  }
                }
             }); 
          });
```

**`HTML code:`**

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <div id = "mainDiv" class = "container" style="padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%" data-role="page" id="pageone"> -->
        <div data-role="page" id="pageone" class="container swipearea" id="mainDiv" style="padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%">
            <div id = "header">
                <span id = "icons">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
                      <span id = "menu"></span>
                    </a>
                    <span onclick="goBack()" id = "back"></span>
                </span>
                <span id = "title">
                    <span id="junos"> JUNOS </span><span id = "genius">GENIUS</span> 
                </span>
            </div>

            <!-- <div id ="body" class="container-fluid" style="position:relative;" data-role="main"> -->
            <div id="body" class="container-fluid"  style="position:relative;">

                  <div id="searchMenu" class="col-xs-4" style="height:400px; overflow-y:auto;padding:0px;display:none;min-width: 250px;background-color:transparent;">
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The jquery code is written in a way that it detects the  motion of finger or mouse cursor.
But when I swipe to right, the side menu isn't appearing. Where is the error?

Comment: jquery event is bound on class 'swipe-area' and and 'swipearea' is used as class name for div. This might be causing it.

Comment: Ummm... How else would you define a class?

Comment: Prepare a demo to check. Put your code here, https://jsfiddle.net/bdonntL6/  -- i have already added the touhswipe plugging and Jquery and Jqm so just add your code, in the html javascript and css boxes and click on update to get the link so you can paste it in your question.

Comment: @Tasos: Sure, I'll do it.....