# Adding swipe functionality to existing side menu for rsesponsive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This isn't a duplicate of another question. This is my own custom code for side menu.
I wrote a custom side menu which will be displayed when clicked on an element. Here is the code:
**`jQuery Code:`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
    $('#slide-nav.navbar .container').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

    // Enter your ids or classes
    var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
    var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
    var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
    var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
    var slidewidth = '80%';
    var menuneg = '-100%';
    var slideneg = '-80%';


    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });


        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');


        $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');


    });


    var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';


    $(window).on("resize", function () {

        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }


    });

});
```

**`HTML code:`**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header cust">
                <a class="navbar-toggle"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="title" href="#"><center><span id="junos"> JUNOS </span><span id = "genius">GENIUS</span></center> </a>
            </div>
        <div id="slidemenu">

          <!-- <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form> -->

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This code works absolutely perfect when clicked on an element. I'd like to add swipe (drag) feature to above code. Which approach can I use? Which is the smoothest way to achieve it?

Comment: There is a plugin called http://hammerjs.github.io/ - Hammer.js, allows you to add gestures to move a content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swipeable side menu not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796546/swipeable-side-menu-not-working)

Comment: @doveyg: that was my own question, I wrote a seperate jQuery plugin as mentioned in that question, but was struck.

Answer (score 0):

try using a jQuery plugin called TouchSwipe